# How to render nth object in a JSON array: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to display the catchPhrase from the followings JSON(it is under company)

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  }
```

I am trying to access the JSON with the following code:

```
export default function Posts() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
    const [user, setUser] = useState([])
    const [activePost, setActivePost] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect (() => {
      return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setPosts(json));
    });

    const displayPosts = () => {
        return posts.map((post) => {
            return <Post setActivePost={setActivePost} setUser={setUser} key={post.id} title={post.title} id={post.userId} body={post.body}></Post>
        })
    }
return (
        <div>
            <h2>Posts</h2>
            {displayPosts()}
            <Modal activePost={activePost} userName={user.name} catchPhrase={user.company.catchPhrase}></Modal>
        </div>
    );
}

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';

export default function Post(props) {
    const onClick = () => {
        props.setActivePost(props);
        return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${props.id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => props.setUser(json))
      .then(()=> {
        const backDrop = document.querySelector('.backdrop');
        const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
        modal.style.display = "block" 
        backDrop.style.display = "block"
        backDrop.addEventListener('click', () => {
            modal.style.display = "none" 
            backDrop.style.display = "none"
        } )   
      })
    };
    
    return (
        <div>   
            <h3 onClick={onClick}>{props.title}</h3> 
        </div>
    )
}
```

I thought I could get that data with "user.company.catchPhrase" but it is returning undefined. If anyone has input on how to get the catchPhrase property from the company object, id appreciate it.

Comment: On your first render, the `user` state variable is an empty array. I don't see you setting it anywhere. Where do you call the `setUser` function to actually put something into the `user` variable?

Comment: my bad, here is the other component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

1. You're calling `useEffect` incorrectly. The way you're doing it will trigger an endless loop of re-renders as nothing is stopping `useEffect` from being called on every render. You should call like so instead:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setPosts(json));
  }, []);
```

Note the empty `[]` as the second parameter.

2. You should not even render that `Modal` element until the user variable is actually set, which only happens when you click on any of the posts. As such, I would actually set your user variable to `null` initially as in `const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);`. And then change the Modal render part to look like this:

```
{user && <Modal
        activePost={activePost}
        userName={user.name}
        catchPhrase={user.company.catchPhrase}
      ></Modal>}
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

On your first render, the `user` state is an empty array. So you can not access `user.company.catchPhrase` and you get `undefined`.

place condition before accessing `user.company.catchPhrase` and you will get your desired output.

like,

```
user.company && user.company.catchPhrase
```

this will give you the value